# how to handle proxy's when dealing with email server?

Tags: java, email, proxy, smtp

I have implemented email class and fetching all attributes from properties file.
Here is my code:

```
static {
        // Load the properties file
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream inputStream = Email.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("/mail.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);`enter code here`
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param to
     *            : mail Sent to
     * @param from
     *            : mail sent from
     * @param subject
     *            : mail's subject
     * @param body
     *            : mail's body
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void sendTextMail(String to, String from, String subject,
            String body) throws Exception {

        if (properties.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot  send mail. Host  data not available.");
        }

        // Authenticate the session with username and password
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication((String) properties
                        .get("mail.login.username"), (String) properties
                        .get("mail.login.password"));
            }
        });

        // Create to and from addresses
        InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);

        // Create the message instance
        // and add the sender, recipient, subject and body.
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(fromAddress);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        msg.setContent(body, "text/plain");

        // Finally send the email
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
```

When i tried to send mail i got this error:
16:48:23,882 ERROR AuthorController:1199 - Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25
Proxy is blocking my server. How to overcome this problem

Comment: Try using TLS on port 465 instead. Port 25 is often blocked because of spammers.

Comment: Are you sure it's a proxy and not just a plain firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Most ISPs block outgoing connections on port 25.  However, you can usually use port 587 for non-encrpyted SMTP communication.

To change the port used you can adjust the Properties instance you setup in the static block:

```
...
properties.load(inputStream);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
...
```

After you confirm that works you may want to put the setting in your `/mail.properties` file:

```
mail.smtp.port:587
```